# C# Remove Part of a String with only knowledge of start and end of the part

Tags: c#, string

This is actual example of what I want to accomplish:

I have this string :

> File Name="Unstuck20140608124131432.txt"
>   Path="Unstuck20140608124131432.txt" Status="Passed" Duration="0.44"

And i want to cut the "Path" attribute from it, so it will look like this:

> File Name="Unstuck20140608124131432.txt" Status="Passed"
>   Duration="0.44"

I don't know nothing about the length of the path or the characters inside the " " of the path.

How can i accomplish it ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to manipulate XML using regular expressions. If so, you'll be *much* better off using [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Replace](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace)

```
string input = @"File Name=""Unstuck20140608124131432.txt"" Path=""Unstuck20140608124131432.txt"" Status=""Passed"" Duration=""0.44""";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"Path=\"".+?\""", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

And for you non-regex fans out there, you can use the split command.  (Nothing against regex.  It is an important part of a balanced programmer diet.)

```
var input = "File Name=\"Unstuck20140608124131432.txt\" Path=\"Unstuck20140608124131432.txt\" Status=\"Passed\" Duration=\"0.44\"";

var tmp = input.Split(new[] { "Path=\"" }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);

var result = tmp[0] + tmp[1].Split(new[] { '"' }, 2)[1];
```

Split the string into 2 parts based on the start of your pattern (Path=").
Take the first part.
Split the 2nd part into 2 parts based on the end of the pattern (").  Take the 2nd part of that.